# Add autocomplete with multiple and creatable reactjs material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want the users to be able to select multiple tags while also allowing them to add a tag if it does not exist, the examples on the material UI documentation work on the `freeSolo` option which works on string / object values as options whereas when we use `multiple`, that changes to an array

How do I implement a multiple creatable with `material-ui`?

My code:

```js
// Fetch Adding tag list
const [listOpen, setListOpen] = useState(false);
const [options, setOptions] = useState<Tag[]>([]);
const loadingTags = listOpen && options.length === 0;

useEffect(() => {
  let active = true;

  if (!loadingTags) {
    return undefined;
  }

  (async () => {
    try {
      const response = await getAllTagsForUser();
      if (active) {
        setOptions(response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })();

  return () => {
    active = false;
  };
}, [loadingTags]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!listOpen) {
    setOptions([]);
  }
}, [listOpen]);


<Autocomplete
  multiple
  id="tags"
  open={listOpen}
  onOpen={() => {
    setListOpen(true);
  }}
  onClose={() => {
    setListOpen(false);
  }}
  options={options}
  disableCloseOnSelect
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.name || ""}
  defaultValue={
    contact?.tags?.map((element) => {
      return { name: element };
    }) || undefined
  }
  renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Checkbox
        icon={icon}
        checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
        style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
        checked={selected}
      />
      {option.name}
    </React.Fragment>
  )}
  style={{ width: 500 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Tags" />
  )}
/>;
```

This is just fetching tags from the server and showing them as options, I understand that to be able to allow adding more, I would need to add `filterOptions` and `onChange` but, can someone please provide an example on how to deal with array there?

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't an quick answer but may someone else could use it. Found this Question buy searching an solution. Didn't find one so I tryed myself and this is what I Created and seems it works.

Based on the original Docs https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#creatable

Complete example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

//Components 
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

//Icons

const filter = createFilterOptions();

export default function AutocompleteTagsCreate() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState([])
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setOptions(data);
    }, [])

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            value={selected}
            multiple
            onChange={(event, newValue, reason, details) => {
                let valueList = selected;
                if (details.option.create && reason !== 'removeOption') {
                    valueList.push({ id: undefined, name: details.option.name, create: details.option.create });
                    setSelected(valueList);
                }
                else {
                    setSelected(newValue);
                }
            }}
            filterSelectedOptions
            filterOptions={(options, params) => {
                const filtered = filter(options, params);

                const { inputValue } = params;
                // Suggest the creation of a new value
                const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option.name);
                if (inputValue !== '' && !isExisting) {
                    filtered.push({
                        name: inputValue,
                        label: `Add "${inputValue}"`,
                        create: true
                    });
                }

                return filtered;
            }}
            selectOnFocus
            clearOnBlur
            handleHomeEndKeys
            id="tags-Create"
            options={options}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => {
                // Value selected with enter, right from the input
                if (typeof option === 'string') {
                    return option;
                }
                // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
                if (option.label) {
                    return option.name;
                }
                // Regular option
                return option.name;
            }}
            renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option.create ? option.label : option.name}</li>}
            freeSolo
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Tags" />
            )}
        />
    );
}

const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Tag1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Tag2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Tag3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Tag4'
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

@4source's solution had some errors for me, fixed it:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

type Options = {
  id?: number;
  label?: string;
  name: string;
  create?: boolean;
};

const filter = createFilterOptions<Options>();

export default function MultiSelectCreatable() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<Options[]>([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<Options[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOptions(data);
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      value={selected}
      multiple
      onChange={(event, newValue, reason, details) => {
        if (details?.option.create && reason !== "removeOption") {
          setSelected([...selected, {
            id: undefined,
            name: details.option.name,
            create: details.option.create,
          }]);
        } else {
            setSelected(newValue.map(value => {
                if (typeof value === "string") {
                    return {
                        id: undefined,
                        name: value,
                        create: true,
                      }
                } else {
                    return value
                }
            }));
        }
      }}
      filterSelectedOptions
      filterOptions={(options, params): Options[] => {
        const filtered = filter(options, params);

        const { inputValue } = params;
        // Suggest the creation of a new value
        const isExisting = options.some((option) => inputValue === option.name);
        if (inputValue !== "" && !isExisting) {
          filtered.push({
            name: inputValue,
            label: `Add "${inputValue}"`,
            create: true,
          });
        }

        return filtered;
      }}
      selectOnFocus
      clearOnBlur
      handleHomeEndKeys
      id="tags-Create"
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => {
        // Value selected with enter, right from the input
        if (typeof option === "string") {
          return option;
        }
        // Add "xxx" option created dynamically
        if (option.label) {
          return option.name;
        }
        // Regular option
        return option.name;
      }}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <li {...props}>{option.create ? option.label : option.name}</li>
      )}
      freeSolo
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Tags" />}
    />
  );
}

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Tag1",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Tag2",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Tag3",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Tag4",
  },
];
```